# Why isn't pip downloading virtualenv?

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv

Here's the output of my shell:

```
Hannahs-MacBook-Pro:Downloads hannah$ pip install virtualenv
Collecting virtualenv
  Downloading virtualenv-15.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.8MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 1.8MB 195kB/s 
Installing collected packages: virtualenv
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/commands/install.py", line 342, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_set.py", line 784, in install
    **kwargs
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_install.py", line 851, in install
    self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root, prefix=prefix)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_install.py", line 1064, in move_wheel_files
    isolated=self.isolated,
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/wheel.py", line 345, in move_wheel_files
    clobber(source, lib_dir, True)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/wheel.py", line 323, in clobber
    shutil.copyfile(srcfile, destfile)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 83, in copyfile
    with open(dst, 'wb') as fdst:
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py'
```

Comment: Use `sudo pip ...` or `pip install --user ...`

Comment: You haven't permissons, try with ```sudo pip install virtualenv```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py'`

You don't have permission to install, use `sudo pip install virtualenv`.

Whenever you get this error `IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied:`, it means that you need to use `sudo`.

Answer (score 3):

You need root access to install (or update) `virtualenv`, try:

```
sudo pip install virtualenv
```